# Modeling with different data types

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, prediction, dataset

My objective is to predict the taxi demand in Manhattan depending on time and location. In order to do so I divided Manhattan into census tracts, 288 spatial areas with approximately the same characteristics, and accumulated the taxi pickups per hour for each census tract. For my analysis I use the year 2015.

Furthermore, I added weather data and attributes of census tracts (population, income, number of subway entrances,...). However, the weather data changes daily but is the same for all tracts. On the other hand, the attributes of the tracts don't vary throughout the year but only spatially.

Could there be problems with my dataset for modeling, since it consists of different types of data?

Comment: Since you are doing both time and location you need a spatial and time correlated time series analysis, not easy.

Comment: Consider adding a predictor for non-holiday weekday.